# category url is still going to 404 error page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

I have tried almost everything , i have even used an extension to over-write the url rewrite but i am not getting the point why i am getting 404 error . I am adding menu using mega menu extension is this an issue ? see the screenshot of the url maybe it will clear some ascpects i am trying to solve this issue from 3 days but no progress . 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing?

Comment: Please follow below steps:
1) Clear mega-menu cache
2) Do re-indexing using php bin/magento indexer:reindex command
3) run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command

Comment: i have disabled the mega menu extension .. but menu is not changed as by default all categories should be visible in menu ?

Comment: How many stores you have?

Comment: 1 store only...

Comment: is this website newly build or this existing webiste

Comment: newly build website .

Answer (score 0):

Hey this issue only occur due to url rewrites in magento so i suggest you to run full indexing once and then clear cache then it might work.

If you find this solution helpful please mark it as solution on upvote.

Comment: no i did run indexing so many times , nothing helped .